# Single or two lists

Tags: list

I have a list of employees. There are two departments and an employee will belong to one of the departments. Both departments have some fields in common and some unique columns. Should I create a single list for departments and have department as choice field and show/hide unique columns based on department selection or would it make more sense to create different lists for each department. What are the possible pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: Feels like this question is very speculative and opinion-based

Comment: You are right. Looking for some suggestions before taking final call.

Comment: Then I will close this question for being "Oppinion based", these questions are off topic here I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with one list with two content types, one content type for each department.

That way you have everything in one list and every content type has it's unique fields and on list level you have the fields that are shared by all the content types.

About the options you mentioned:

1. Using Choice field

   **Pros:** You have all the employees in one list and can filter, group etc. OOTB

   **Cons:** Requires more work to implement the column hiding functionality based  on the choice field value
2. Two lists

   **Pros:** Its very easy to do it

   **Cons:** You don't have OOTB viewing, grouping, filtering functionality in one place for all the employees, so some more work needed to get that functionality